# OpenGL gluPerspective Issues, No Display

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having trouble going from the explanation of gluPerspective found here: http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/ to the actual input parameters needed for the function.

I have a cube that I'm displaying stuff in.  The coordinates of the cube range from -10 to 10 in every direction.

Can someone give me an example of the gluPerspective() call needed to display that region?  I've tried gluPerspective(26,w/h,10,30) thinking that the angle of 26 degrees is in the angle from the focal point (10 units from the box) to the middle of the box's top side, which means I have 10 units to the close edge and 30 to the far.  However when I change from glOrtho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f); to gluPerspective(...) nothing is displayed on the screen.

Comment: is object you want to see closer then 10 points or further then 30 from the camera?

Comment: It moves between the points -10 z and +10 z.

Comment: you have understood some params of gluPerspective wrong. look at this http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing a translate to get your model into the view frustum, and your clipping parameters could be a little better. When you use glPerspective the camera starts at the origin, so your camera is inside of the cube you are drawing. You probably can't tell because the faces at z=-10 are getting clipped; change your near clipping plane to 5 or 1 or something and you should see it.

The camera looks down the negative Z axis by default, so you should translate your model by (0, 0, -20) or so. Clipping parameters of near=5 and far=40 should let it be visible; make sure near is greater than 0 at a minimum.

Hope this helps!